# Invisible reCAPTCHA missing input response

Tags: javascript, php, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to make a page with an invisible `reCAPTCHA` and I am having trouble getting it to work.

Client Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-8C+3bW/ArbXinsJduAjm9O7WNnuOcO+Bok/VScRYikawtvz4ZPrpXtGfKIewM9dK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        $('#formcomplete').click(function (e) {
            grecaptcha.reset();
            document.getElementById('form').checkValidity();
            grecaptcha.execute();
            return false;
        });
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }
    </script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
    <style>
        .centerize {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black; overflow: hidden;">
    <form method='post' action='_resources/signup.php' id="form">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); max-width: 50%;">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" size="64" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                    <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email' placeholder='email@example.com' size="64" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check" style="text-align: center;">
                <label class="form-check-label" style="color: white">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="emaillist" value="emaillisttrue">
                    Add me to the email list to learn about future releases.
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check" style="text-align: center;">
                <label class="form-check-label" style="color: white">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tac" value="tactrue" required>
                    I accept the <a href="./legal.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" >Terms and Conditions & Privacy Policy</a>.
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class='btn btn-default centerize' id="formcomplete">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
             data-sitekey="keeeeey"
             data-callback="onSubmit"
             data-theme="dark"
             data-size="invisible">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and the Server Side validation:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $emaillist = stripslashes($_POST['emaillist']);
    $tac = stripslashes($_POST['tac']);
    //... verify that you have a name email and accepted the terms
    $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",false,stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query(array(
                'secret' => 'keeeeey',
                'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
                'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            ))
        )
    )));
    if (json_decode($verify)->success==true) {
        //... handle normal case
    } else {
        var_dump($verify);
        //header("Location: ...");
    }
}
```

When I browse to the page everything shows up fine, input is validated (chrome shows "please check this box to continue" if you didn't), and everything works up until I hit submit. After hitting submit I get directed to the form's POST endpoint at which the `var_dump` throws a discouraging `string(75) "{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }"`.

**Now here's what perplexes me.** If I browse to the page, fill in all the details and then open up the chrome dev console and enter `grecaptcha.execute();` the form gets submitted and everything works fine, the `reCAPTCHA` request goes fine, and all the stuff that happens during the successful verify path server side happens. I have no idea why this happens.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is a perplexing issue. I'm looking over your code to see if I spot anything odd... other than how you are handling the post input (I use their php lib include to do that)... so far nothing jumping out at me :(

Comment: Have you tried moving `document.getElementById('form').submit();` into the click action, and not use the onSubmit callback?

Comment: Doing that yields the same error.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check if it was submitting differently, but sounds like no. Which leads me into a wall on any suggestions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the

```
<script>
        $('#formcomplete').click(function (e) {
            grecaptcha.reset();
            document.getElementById('form').checkValidity();
            grecaptcha.execute();
            return false;
        });
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }
    </script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
```

to just before the closing `body` tag worked somehow. Probably needed the DOM to be defined before attempting to use elements on it or something.